# Gridview binding with row header also column header from same table

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

i want display data in gridview in matrix concept using asp.net,C# 4.0 & oracle 11g

able to bind data dynamically in gridview when page load event

My requirement is

```
Activity1    activity2    activity3 ...  activity 10     

Monday & date

tuesday & date

wednesday & date
```

.
.
.
.

```
Sunday & date
```

The Code i have tried

```
protected void GetActivity()
{
    string query2 = "Select ACTIVITY1,ACTIVITY2,ACTIVITY3,ACTIVITY4,ACTIVITY5,ACTIVITY6,TOTALDURTN from DAILY_ACTIVITIES order by ACTIVITYNO asc";
    using (OracleConnection CON = new OracleConnection(strConnection))
    {
        using (OracleCommand command2 = new OracleCommand(query2, CON))
        {
            CON.Open();
            DataTable DTBLE2 = new DataTable();
            OracleDataAdapter OracleDA2 = new OracleDataAdapter(command2);
            OracleDA2.Fill(DTBLE2);
            ViewState["dt"] = DTBLE2;
            this.BindGrid();
        }
    }
}

protected void BindGrid()
{
    DisplayGridView.DataSource = ViewState["dt"] as DataTable;
    DisplayGridView.DataBind();
}

protected void OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    this.BindGrid();
}

protected void OnCancel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DisplayGridView.EditIndex = -1;
    this.BindGrid();
}

protected void OnUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (sender as LinkButton).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    string ACTIVITY1 = (row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
    string ACTIVITY2 = (row.Cells[1].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
    string ACTIVITY3 = (row.Cells[2].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
    string ACTIVITY4 = (row.Cells[3].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
    string ACTIVITY5 = (row.Cells[4].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
    string ACTIVITY6 = (row.Cells[5].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
    string TOTALDURTN = (row.Cells[6].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;

    DataTable dt = ViewState["dt"] as DataTable;
    dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["ACTIVITY1"] = ACTIVITY1;
    dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["ACTIVITY2"] = ACTIVITY2;
    dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["ACTIVITY3"] = ACTIVITY3;
    dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["ACTIVITY4"] = ACTIVITY4;
    dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["ACTIVITY5"] = ACTIVITY5;
    dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["ACTIVITY6"] = ACTIVITY6;
    dt.Rows[row.RowIndex]["TOTALDURTN"] = TOTALDURTN;
    ViewState["dt"] = dt;
    DisplayGridView.EditIndex = -1;
    this.BindGrid();
}


protected void DisplayGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.Cells.Count > 0)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
            //e.Row.Cells[0].Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        }
    }
}
```

can i do it with gridview if so how ?

Comment: Storing a `DataTable` in ViewState is normally not a good idea. All data must be serialized and will be sent to the client as text. All the more since the `GridView` will retain it's state anyway if `ViewState` is enabled. Instead either reload it from database which is the most efficient and robust solution or use the `Session`(server memory) when you don't have many clients.

Comment: Apart from that, what is the real issue, where did you get stuck? Currently it's not clear what you're actually asking. Is the sql query the problem?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I want to display data like http://postimg.org/image/c82t6gusp/    Activity1,activity2 etc as Column header and date as row header